# Open sports data

Tags: uses-of-open-data, sports

Today you can find all sorts of data in an open format. Most financial data, polling and government databases, just about every baseball play ever played.

However this open data paradigm hasn't reached across the rest of the sporting world. Getting NFL, NBA, NHL and NCAA data remains quite difficult and legally confusing. This is making it difficult to create an open data science interest in professional sports data.

Does anyone know about any projects that are working on making this kind of data easily accessible via API or other database forma?

Comment: have you explored Wikipedia?

Comment: I assume http://sportsdatabase.com/ does not meet your needs?

Comment: If you are interested in the PL: http://www.football-data.co.uk/englandm.php

1994 - 20016.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open Sports Data has been around for awhile, as sports have some extremely involved fans.

Here is some data, references, and resources:

### General Sports

[Sports Data Query Language (SDQL)](http://sdql.com/)
[SportsDataBase (SDQL) Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/SportsDataBase)
[Sports Data Visualization using the Sports Data Query Language](http://viz.sdql.com/)
[Download KillerSports.com's Data](http://killersports.com/download)
[API](http://sportsdatabase.com/api)
[More Databases](http://www.hardballtimes.com/databases-for-sabermetricians-part-one/)

### Baseball

[Lahman Database (.csv/.sql/.mdb)](http://baseball1.com/content/view/57/82/)
[Retrosheet – Play-By-Play Files, Game Logs, Schedules](http://www.retrosheet.org/)
[Japanese Baseball Data](http://baseballguru.com/jalbright/stats.html)
[Baseball Tools - Tools for Working with Baseball Data](https://github.com/matgargano/baseball-tools)
[Baseball Databank](http://www.baseball-databank.org/)
[Baseball Reference .com Data](http://www.baseball-reference.com/data/foo/)

### Football

[The Football Project – Play-By-Play Data](http://web.archive.org/web/20160310134936/http://www.footballproject.com/)
[Advanced Football Analytics](http://web.archive.org/web/20160404162056/http://www.advancedfootballanalytics.com/index.php/home/stats/advanced-team-stats)
[more football](http://www.10flow.com/tag/football/)
[SportsDatabase.com makes box score data researchable](http://sportsdatabase.com/)
[Advanced Football Analytics' Play-By-Play Data Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20140813215747/http://www.advancedfootballanalytics.com/2010/04/play-by-play-data.html)
[Play-By-Play Repository of Older NFL Data via 10flow](https://github.com/10flow/playbyplay)
[10flow allows you to roll your own NFL Play-By-Play Datasets](http://football.10flow.com/)

### College Football

[College Football Data Warehouse](http://cfbdatawarehouse.com/)
Disclaimer: the next two repositories are mine:
[College football datasets from cbstats.com](https://github.com/jalbertbowden/college-football-data)
[NCAA Football Profits](https://github.com/jalbertbowden/ncaa-football-profits)

### Basketball

[DatabaseBasketball Stats Database Download](http://databasebasketball.com/stats_download.htm)

### Hockey

[Hockey Databank – Yahoo Group](http://sports.groups.yahoo.com/group/hockey-databank/files/)

Answer (score 4):

Check out [data.world](https://data.world/) - a social network for data people, that are building the world’s most collaborative, abundant, and meaningful data resource.
Below are some example sports-related datasets, and you can search the platform by keyword to find other related data. If you don't see what you're looking for, you can create a dataset page and add a 'contributors-wanted' tag to let other users know you're looking for that data and would like to collaborate.

Example Datasets:
[1976-2015 NBA Draft Data](https://data.world/rvino88/1976-to-2015-nba-draft-data)

[Lahmans Baseball Database](https://data.world/bgadoci/lahmans-baseball-database)

[Search data.world for Keyword "Sports"](https://data.world/search?q=sports)

Answer (score 2):

There's a bunch more sports data sets constantly being added to listen on this page at [Sports-Statistics.com](https://sports-statistics.com/sports-data/sports-data-sets-for-data-modeling-visualization-predictions-machine-learning/), including Fifa datasets, soccer datasets and APIs, cricket, baseball, f1 etc.

aside from that, i have been playing with the [NBASense API](http://nbasense.com/nba-api/) to extract box scores and stats from NBA websites.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in Golf, you can find lots of data about the European Golf Tour here:
http://www.europeantour.com/europeantour/stats/season=2016/categoryid=1/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could be interested in our API Restful service released in Open Data.

For all info go on [Sports Open Data](http://sportsopendata.net)

Comment: Would be better if you include also some info in your answer. Not just a link with a title.