# Sport's APIs For Headshots and Stats

Tags: api, sports

I'm currently building an program that would benefit from higher quality images of University's Logos(NCAA, NAIA, etc.),head shots of athletes, and general statistical data(Games played, etc). The information needs to be quite accurate. I was looking into ESPN's API and it seems they no longer do public keys or are accepting new strategic partnerships. Is there anything else of that quality that is trustworthy?

Comment: Anything here? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/9822/1511

Comment: @philshem nothing there sadly. I'd really like to not scrap espn website for their headshots but it may come down to that.

Answer (score 1):

For soccer players, Kaggle hosts the **[FIFA 18 Complete Player Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/thec03u5/fifa-18-demo-player-dataset)**. Accessing the data requires registration.

> 17k+ players, 70+ attributes extracted from the latest edition of FIFA

Including a URL to each player's photo is in the CSV:

[image]

Example URL: https://cdn.sofifa.org/1x/18/players/20801.png

[image]

*Note on player photo URL*: needs to be slightly modified, based on my testing and this [comment](https://www.kaggle.com/thec03u5/fifa-18-demo-player-dataset/discussion/58777).

> I replaced the /48/ with /1x/ on my local copy to get all of the photos to work.

https://cdn.sofifa.org/1x/18/players/237419.png

Note on original data source:

> The data is scraped from the website https://sofifa.com by extracting the Player personal data and Player Ids and then the playing and style statistics.